# Chat para IOS com Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

Estou procurando uma forma mais rápida de desenvolvimento de um app tipo whatsapp para IOS.
Como sou muito novo em Swift gostaria de saber se existe algo tipo um "app esqueleto" que eu pudesse dar uma melhorada no visual e apontar pra o meu web service.
Existe essa alternativa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construi a parte de chat deste app - [Flips - Picture Your Words](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-_DmyHzQQ6w) - usando [PubNub](https://www.pubnub.com/solutions/chat/). Funciona perfeitamente. No site do PubNub tem exemplos de como fazer um chat app (Objective-C e Swift).